# NoSuchMethodError when deploying Spring Boot to Weblogic

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic

I've got a Spring Boot application running fine locally via the built in tomcat server but I'm having issues deploying it as a war file in Weblogic 12.2. I've followed the "85.1 Create a deployable war file" section of the Spring Boot reference guide to build the war file, created a new Weblogic managed server to host it and followed the deployment install steps on Weblogic but get the below exception when clicking start "servicing all requests" on the deployment. Any suggestions?

**Dependencies section of build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile(
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.8.RELEASE',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
        'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.2',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security',
        'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    )
    testCompile(
        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test',
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    )
    providedRuntime (
        'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    )
}
```

**Exception received from Weblogic when clicking start "servicing all requests":**

```
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment.initPropertySources(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;Ljavax/servlet/ServletConfig;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:162)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1420)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1359)
        Loads more weblogic errors here.
```

**My application entry point appears to be okay:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring boot embedded with a tomcat servlet container. Why would you want to deploy spring-boot app on weblogic?

Comment: Is there any way to remove that? Unless I've misunderstood the docs say adding the above "providedRuntime" dependency excludes it? We just use Weblogic as our app server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a weblogic deployment descriptor as said in [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic). Create a file named `weblogic.xml` and add this code to the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Now put the `weblogic.xml` file into `WEB-INF` folder so that full path will be `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`.

**Update:**
Add a empty `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to `WEB-INF/` folder.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
</beans>
```

And your `build.gradle` add dependency

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
```

Also remove

```
providedRuntime (
    'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
)
```

Comment: Done and confirmed by checking the war file contents but still the same error. I'm not sure if it's weblogic trying to substitute it's own jars over the spring ones?

Comment: I didn't think so. Could you please remove your `providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'` from `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Then problem could be somewhere else. :(

Comment: Looks like the Weblogic install needed patching to the latest version. Not had this issue since.